# Mattermost docker preview

Tags: docker, port, publish, mattermost, manjaro

I am an arch newbie and I have been trying to install preview of mattermost(slack alternative) on docker to try it out. I have been following the official guide.

Arch

```
Install Docker using the following commands:

pacman -S docker
systemctl enable docker.service
systemctl start docker.service
gpasswd -a <username> docker
newgrp docker

Start Docker container:

docker run --name mattermost-preview -d --publish 8065:8065 mattermost/mattermost-preview

When Docker is done fetching the image, open http://localhost:8065/ in your browser.
```

Unfortunately I can't open the localhost:8065 service.

I have listed this issue in error trackers of both Docker
https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/23730

I installed it on ubuntu 14.04 and still encountering the same problem.

output of  docker info

```
Containers: 3
 Running: 1
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 2
Images: 2
Server Version: 1.11.2
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 33
 Dirperm1 Supported: false
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins: 
 Volume: local
 Network: null host bridge
Kernel Version: 3.13.0-32-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 3.767 GiB
Name: warmachine
ID: FICU:HLW6:7J7X:NFWJ:HX27:32U4:HQZB:I2UW:K5TI:DDAB:EBC3:F2LW
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug mode (client): false
Debug mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: No swap limit support
```

output of docker version

```
Client:
Version:      1.11.2    
API version:  1.23
Go version:   go1.5.4
Git commit:   b9f10c9
Built:        Wed Jun  1 21:47:50 2016
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
Version:      1.11.2
API version:  1.23
Go version:   go1.5.4
Git commit:   b9f10c9
Built:        Wed Jun  1 21:47:50 2016
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Comment: @vitr
 I hope this is what u meant. i ran the docker ps -a command and this is my output. It says the docker container should be available through host port.

 CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                           COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                              NAMES
7d5f522a1df2        mattermost/mattermost-preview   "/bin/sh -c ./docker-"   4 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds        3306/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8065->8065/tcp   mattermost-preview

Comment: If you can't see the container without `-a` that means it's not running

Comment: @vitr I can view the container without -a option. So how to proceed from here.

Comment: I just tried mattermost-preview on ubuntu, got the same issue as you(( good luck hunting this down

Comment: I too tried running it on a fresh install of ubuntu. I think its got something to do with docker rather than mattermost.

Comment: doesn't matter arch or ubuntu, I've got `refused to connect`

Comment: they messed up something, try to open an issue on github

Comment: yes.same here.will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case mysql is not yet ready at the time when mattermost starts.

The solution is to clone the official repo to my local directory > Go into the directory > Edit  **docker-entry.sh** file and change the line `sleep 20` to some higher value like 100.

After that execute

`docker build -t somename/mattermost .
 docker run --name mattermost-preview -d --publish 8065:8065  somename/mattermost`

If it still doesnt work replace `8065:8065` part with `SomeRandomPort:8065` and execute above line with a different name for docker container.

Thanks to https://github.com/joelnb for the solution.

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be an issue with the packaging of the app. It's been [reported on their github](https://github.com/mattermost/mattermost-docker-preview/issues/2)

To rule out any issues with your own docker install, you can always test the port forwarding with something like:

```
docker run -it --rm -p 8080:80 debian /bin/sh -c "apt-get update; apt-get install -yq netcat; nc -l -p 80"
```

And then in another terminal:

```
nc -q 1 127.0.0.1 8080 <<EOF
hello world
EOF
```

If you see a "hello world" on the docker terminal, then your docker install is fine.

Comment: Definitely a packaging issue - their docker image simply does `sleep 20` after starting mysql so it may well not be ready. I made a [pull request](https://github.com/mattermost/mattermost-docker-preview/pull/5).